# fscanf in a function (Language C)

Tags: c, file

I'm reading a text file char by char using fscanf();

I've tried to pass my FILE pointer to a function, to keep reading there, but I'm getting stuck in a loop.

```
void keepReading(FILE *fp){
     char c;
     fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
}

/* main */
fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
while(c!='A'){
    keepReading(fp);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the text file you're reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `c` in `keepReading()` is local to that function. Return the value to your loop and test that

```
char keepReading(FILE *fp){
     char c;
     fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
     return c;
}

/* main */
fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
while(c!='A'){
    c = keepReading(fp);
}
```

Comment: That's good unless you hit EOF before you get the 'A'; then you're likely to back in an infinite loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `fscanf` for this, if you are going to read in a file character by character, use the function that reads characters, `fgetc`.  `fscanf` is for reading formatted data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("...", "r");
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == 'A') break;
        // do stuff
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```